Mysql: Determine amount of time a value is found in a range of time when row count / time entries are not linear
I am wondering if there is an easier way to figure out the amount of time a value exists in a set of row (time range) when the row set it not linear (i.e. can't just figure out how many rows are < a value.
Lets start with an example



ID
Time
Value




111
2024-09-15 20:00:08
1


112
2024-09-15 20:00:36
1


113
2024-09-15 20:01:00
0


114
2024-09-15 20:01:06
0


115
2024-09-15 20:01:45
1


116
2024-09-15 20:02:03
1


117
2024-09-15 20:02:07
1


118
2024-09-15 20:02:44
0


119
2024-09-15 20:03:00
1


120
2024-09-15 20:03:11
1



** The above example is exaggerated for explanation purposes, normally the time increments are between 3-8 seconds.
So normally, I've been using a function/stored procedure to determine when the value flips to the zero then when it goes back to 1 again, subtract the last time from the previous and store that in seconds in a variable. Repeat until I've processed the range and add the variables as i go.
Here is an example, where i want to find how much time the value was at zero:
row 113 = start 1:00
row 115 = end   1:45
45 seconds
row 118 start  2:44
row 119 end    3:00
16 seconds
Total time value = 0 in the range = 45 + 16 = 61 seconds.
It strikes me that there may be a way to achieve this in pure SQL query instead of a function? But I don't know how or where to start. The final goal is to insert this into a a charting app (Grafana) and simplify things.

What version of MySQL Server are you using? Query SELECT VERSION();

I have 2 DB's
MariaDB: 10.9.8-MariaDB-1:10.9.8+maria~ubu2004
Mysql: 8.0.32
I'm migrating to MySQL (AWS Aurora)

I don't think you need any function here. In your query first calculate an additional column for value span, regardless of next value (can be done using lag), and then simply sum that value using grou by value

I'm just learning about the use of lag from your reply, but it seems to describe being able to read the previous row data but in my example above and in my case, the start row may be more than one or thousands of rows prior to the end time row. I will play more with lag but an example would be extremely helpful.
